# Validar TextBox que solo permita numeros enteros VB evento TextChanged

Tags: .net, vb

Buen dia comunidad.

He podido realizar la validación para el evento KeyPress, para que solo me acepte números, con el siguiente código:

```
Private Sub TextBox3_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyPress    
   e.Handled = Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) And Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
End Sub
```

Pero mi duda es si copio y pego en el TextBox me acepta letras..
Como valido cuando el texto cambia (propiedad TextChanged)

Comment: estas cosas se solucionan mejor usando un spinner sin los controles de movimiento ;)... pero si no podes, cual es el problema que tuviste con el evento textchanged?

Comment: winforms o wpf?

Comment: Hola, yo tuve que hacer eso pero en c# que es el lenguaje en que programo, si quieres te pongo el código y tu lo conviertes a tu lenguaje, dime si te interesa

Comment: Ya se pudo con expresion regular  `Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    TextBox3.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(TextBox3.Text, "[^\d]", "")    'Elimina todos los caracteres a excepción de los números.
End Sub`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo se me ocurre capturar el evento `TextChanged` y mediante una expresión regular quitar todos los caracteres que no sean numéricos:

```
Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    TextBox3.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(TextBox3.Text, "[^\d]", "")    'Elimina todos los caracteres a excepción de los números.
End Sub
```

Comment: Excelente... funciono, gracias